# jquery or javascript div background image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, background

I have a problem in site that I build.I search google and stackoverflow but I can't find anything that could help me.I have one div with content search engine,text etc...and I have background image.So can you tell me how to change div background image every like 2-3 second or whatever i set with fade effect, and please I'm noob with jquery or javascript so be a patient.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
    <div id="banner">

  <img class="img1" height="251" width="650" alt="img1" src="images/banner1.jpg"/>

  <img class="img2" height="251" width="650" alt="img2" src="images/banner2.jpg"/>

</div>
```

jquery code

```
 jQuery.timer = function (interval, callback)
 {

 var interval = interval || 100;

if (!callback)
    return false;

_timer = function (interval, callback) {
    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(self.id);
    };

    this.internalCallback = function () {
        callback(self);
    };

    this.reset = function (val) {
        if (self.id)
            clearInterval(self.id);

        var val = val || 100;
        this.id = setInterval(this.internalCallback, val);
    };

    this.interval = interval;
    this.id = setInterval(this.internalCallback, this.interval);

    var self = this;
};

return new _timer(interval, callback);
};

var current_panel = 2;
var animation_duration = 2500;  
$.timer(6000, function (timer) {  
    switch(current_panel){  
        case 1:  
           $("#banner .img1").fadeIn(800);

           $("#banner .img2").fadeOut(800);
            current_panel = 2; 
        break; 
        case 2: 
            $("#banner .img2").fadeIn(800);

             $("#banner .img1").fadeOut(800);
            current_panel = 1; 
        break; 

        timer.reset(12000);  
     }  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to change background images with fade effects without additional markup. You didn't provide any code, so I've made a synthetic example.

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        ... 
    </div>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
/*
    this is your main container 
*/
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

/*
    this one is needed to provide 
    independent background, when it fades
    your content will still be available for seeing
*/
.bg {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:0;
}

/*
    your content, obviously :)
*/
.content {
    position:relative;
    top:-300px;
    z-index:1;
    padding:5px; /*just for better looking*/
}
```

And some jquery:

```
//in your case, here must be URLs for images
var arr = ["yellow", "blue", "green", "red"]; 
var i = 0;

var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    //when bg fades, we don't want to see  
    //transparent background                             
    $('.container').css('background-color', arr[i]); 

    //make transparent, change background, make visible again
    $('.bg').animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color': arr[i]}).animate({opacity: 1});
    });

    //this can be random
    i++;
    if (i >= arr.length)
        i = 0;
}, 2000); //change 2000 if you want different time between changes


//this one is illustating, how to stop background loop
//with "clearInterval". You might want to use it on :hover or smth like that
setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    }, 20000);
```

It's not very flexible solution, because you need to know exact size of the elements, but I don't think you'll use images of different sizes for background.

p.s. Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/7xVAu/115/

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can start here at the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). If you don't understand that stuff try looking for some good [javascript or JQuery books](http://oreilly.com/javascript/). Also [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is very helpful for beginner programmers.

Comment: I once heard if you build a man a fire you will keep him warm for a night, but if you set a man on fire he will be warm for the rest of his life.

Comment: I try this later but for now I must build this

Comment: When I am learning a new function of javascript or JQuery I always start at the docs. They are _the_ definitive guide.